# Forcing Core Data to refresh an NSManagedObject from a previous stored version when an updated version is already in memory

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm having trouble forcing Core Data to refresh some of my NSManagedObject subclasses in a document based iOS app I'm writing.

The problem is in dealing with the situation where the user loads a second document while there are unsaved changes in the current document
At the moment, if the user loads the first document again, the unsaved changes show up.
The documents are loaded using an NSFetchRequest for the document's root object. This fetch request has the property `-setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects:` set to `YES` and the property
 `-setIncludesPendingChanges:` set to `NO` I'm certain that they aren't being saved to the persistent store, since terminating the app and restarting it causes the original unaltered document to show up.  Also, I have SQL debug turned on, and it shows that the app isn't fetching from the relevant tables the second time around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://www.section42.de/coredata-how-to-revert-a-managed-object-to-its-original-state/) might help you, which adds a category for reverting changes to NSManagedObject.  Best of luck.

```
#import "NSManagedObject+RevertChanges.h"

@implementation NSManagedObject (NSManagedObject_RevertChanges)

- (void) revertChanges {
    // Revert to original Values
    NSDictionary *changedValues = [self changedValues];
    NSDictionary *committedValues = [self committedValuesForKeys:[changedValues allKeys]];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator;
    id key;
    enumerator = [changedValues keyEnumerator];

    while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {
        NSLog(@"Reverting field ""%@"" from ""%@"" to ""%@""", key, [changedValues objectForKey:key], [committedValues objectForKey:key]);
        [self setValue:[committedValues objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @StefanKendall for your advice.  Was only trying to help him, should have been a comment i suppose.  I cannot now however delete this answer as it did seem to help since he marked it as the correct answer.

Comment: copied in the code for posterity. This makes this an answer.

Comment: Ah,I see. I was confused by your comment.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is already answered, but what about using method refreshObject:mergeChanges: of NSManagedObjectContext?

see [NSManagedObject Class Reference refreshObject:mergeChanges:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506224-refreshobject)